# Vectorizing half tone images

Tags: vector-graphics, artifacts

Vectorizing continuous tone images is often met with color palette reduction and visual artifacts. Half-tone images, on the hand, have constant patterns in their tones, which would intuitively lead to the conclusion that these images can be vectorized with greater success, if without any visual artifacts at all.
   Failing to find any sufficient comparisons against vectorizing continuous tone images and half-tone images on separate research, I now pose this: **What behaviors occur during vectorization of "raster" half-tone images?**

Comment: Well, kind of, if your target is to do the half toned image. But the target is usually to do the original image and your now 2 steps away form achieving that. Its a bit like swapping a fillet stake dinners ingredients with that of a sandwich and saying its easier to do. Sure.

Comment: Vector formats also support colour gradients etc, for which palette reduction would be highly detrimental.There have been papers that describe ways of making use of this.